# gitlab pipeline webhook events are not emitted with all status

Tags: gitlab, webhooks, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-api

I added a webhook for `pipeline` and `job` event types. Currently `pipeline` has only one `job` to `echo hello` and is using shared runner. The receiver for hook is simple webserver.

According to [list-pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#list-project-pipelines), possible status for pipeline are `created`, `waiting_for_resource`, `preparing`, `pending`, `running`, `success`, `failed`.

However, I am **NOT** receiving events with status `created`, `waiting_for_resource`, `preparing`, `pending`.

The **first status** I receive is `running` for `pipeline` event. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have on mind, that not all events have to come through webhooks. There can be temporary network problem, e.t.c.. Have some backup plane, like call list pipelines / list jobs regularly to maintain correct state of gitlab world in your application. It is also first thing to implement and webhooks are "only" for making things more reactive.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with GitLab, its platform is faster. Normally, through webhooks it will show only `running`, `success`, or `failed` status.

The behavior could change with custom runners, where a runner with low resources can slow down the process and show a status like `preparing` or `pending`.

Also, if a pipeline has dependencies with other pipelines, it will show the `pending` status.